# Floated elements and top margin

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem that I could work around but it annoys me that I don't understand it. Maybe you can help. I have a header with a nav bar inside which is floated to the right. Now when I add margin-top to the nav and set it equal to say 10% it is not sizing relative the the parents height. Instead it appears much further down the page. Heres my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header img {
  float: left;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="" alt="Reece Barrett's" height="" width="" />

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <!--
                 -->
      <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a>
      </li>
      <!--
                 -->
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Why you need `margin-top` in `%`?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I'm new to web development so I dont know the best practices. I assumed it would help when making the page responsive. Am I wrong for doing this?

Comment: Do you wants to keep navigation in middle of header that why using margin in  %?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I want it floated to the right. With a small amount of margin at the bottom. So more than half way.

Comment: In my opinion you should have a fixed height header (not in `%`) and use fixed value for `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` bcz `height` in `%` will change according to viewport height and it might not look good in some resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `header` to be auto height, Use `min-height` instead of using height, also remove `overflow:hidden` otherwise this will hide overflowed content.

```
header {
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

For more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `min-height: 10%`

heres the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4sg5b72/

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it using the positioning absolute & relative.
Codepen: http://codepen.io/rezasan/pen/YGmVGo

```
    header {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 10%;
      width: 100%;
      position:relative;
    }
    header img {
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
    nav {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 30%;
      text-align: center;
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      top:50%;
      transform:translateY(-50%);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
body{
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}
header{
background-color: yellow;
height: 10%;
width: 100%;
}
header img{
float: left;
}
nav{
float: right;
background-color: grey;
width: 30%;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10%;
}
nav ul{
list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li{
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="" alt="Reece Barrett's" height="" width="" />
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Porfolio</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

It's because **overflow: hidden** of **Head**